# Google Webmaster query api returning 403 error

Tags: google-search-console, api, 403-forbidden

We are using php library to fetch webmaster query API data and getting 403 permission denied error while able to fetch the same data using webmaster analytics tool.

The following are the things which we implemented to fetch webmaster data:

- We have created one project with auth2 credentials, API key, service API key to get webmaster data.  [image]
- We can access query api data from webmaster analytics data tool.
- I am calling same api with above given auth2 credentials and getting 403 (Permission denied) error. [image]

Also getting the error if we are calling same api using api_key.

Please let us know what we are missing or how to access webmaster data using php library auth2 or using api key. Also attaching screen shot for the same if in line images are missing.

Comment: I haven't used google API's but I do know that in order to access protected content, you need to have a valid username and password. Once logged in, cookies are stored on your computer so you won't have to login for every protected page you try to access. If you try to access a protected page without the right credentials, then a 403 code is normal (aka access denied error).